# Why don't images load on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

So when it comes to loading the page on mobile devices, images start loading but they fail to load completely. I have already tried to preload the images before the page is displayed, but it still fails to load. I also tried to minimize the amount of images, but even with one image it fails to load. The images are also compressed, so size is not the issue with loading. Sometimes when the page is refreshed, the images load; however, other times they don't. Is this an ios/browser issue? Possibly something with css? Maybe too much going on at once?

By the way, the images load fine locally, but on the live site, the loading issue persists. Could it be the hosting service?

HERE IS THE LIVE PAGE (loads fine on desktop but not mobile)
http://thelittlepenguinshop.com/shop.php

All help is appreciated.

```
<?php
include 'db/connect.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php include 'includes/head.php' ?>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imgs = [
        "img/shopView/IMG_1932.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2657.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2655.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2654.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2652.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2647.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2645.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2643.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2641.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2639.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2637.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2635.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2633.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2628.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2627.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2624.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2623.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2619.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2618.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2615.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2610.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2608.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2606.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2602.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2600.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2598.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2594.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2591.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2589.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2587.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2584.jpg",
        "img/shopView/DSCF2580.jpg",
        "img/shopView/cELSM.jpg",
        "img/shopView/cBae.jpg",
    ]
    function preload(all_imgs) {
        $(all_imgs).each(function() {
            $("<img/>")[0].src = this;
        });
    }
    preload(imgs);
</script>
<body>
<?php include 'includes/body-internals/mainnav.php' ?>

<input type="hidden" class="activeCheck" id="shop">

<div id='sh-ul-wrap' class='card'>
    <div id="sh-ul">
        <?php
            $start_from = 1;
            if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
            $start_from = ($page-1) * 12; 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM items LIMIT $start_from, 12"; 
            if ($result = $db->query($sql)) {
                if ($count = $result->num_rows) {

                    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

                        echo '
        <div class="li">
            <a href="itempage.php?item_id=', $row->item_id, '">
                <div class="sh-it-wrap">
                    <div class="sh-it-names">', $row->item_name, ' <span style="font-weight:300"> | ', $row->item_type, '</span></div>
                    <div class="sh-it-prices">$', $row->item_price, '</div>
                    <img src="img/shopView/', $row->item_img, '">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
                        ';              

                    }

                    $result->free();
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='shop_pg_num'>
    <ul class='card'>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php include 'includes/body-internals/footer.php' ?>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //keeps the list within the widths of 500 and 950 pixels
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function sh_ul_wrap_width() {
            $('#sh-ul-wrap').css('width', '950');
            if (window.innerWidth >= 1500) {
                $('#sh-ul-wrap').css('width', '950');
            } else if (window.innerWidth <= 500) {
                $('#sh-ul-wrap').css('width', '500');
            }
            $('.sh-it-wrap').css('height', String($('.sh-it-wrap img').height()));
        }
        setInterval(sh_ul_wrap_width, 500);

        //displays number of pages based on how many items are in the database
        function num_pages() {
            var x = '<?php $v = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items"); $count = $v->num_rows; echo $count; ?>';
            var num_pages = Math.ceil(x / 12);

            for (var i = 1; i <= num_pages; i++) {
                $('#shop_pg_num ul').append(
                    '<a href="shop.php?page=' + String(i) + '"><li>' + String(i) + '</li></a>'
                );
            }
        }

        num_pages();

    });
</script>
</html>
```

HERE IS THE CSS

```
#sh-ul-wrap {
        width: 950px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #sh-ul-wrap {
        width: 90vw;
    }
}

#sh-ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*large screen DEFAULT 4 items per row*/
#sh-ul .li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#sh-ul .li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transistion: 0.2s ease color;
}
#sh-ul .li a:hover {
    color: #60DFE5;
}
/*#sh-ul .li > span {
    display: block;
}*/

.sh-it-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.sh-it-wrap img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.sh-it-names {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.sh-it-prices {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

/*medium screen causes 3 items per row*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
    #sh-ul .li {
        width: 33.3%;
   }
}

/*small screen causes 2 items per row*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   #sh-ul .li {
        width: 50%;
   }

   .sh-it-wrap {
        width: 75%;
   }
}

#shop_pg_num {
    text-align: center;
}

#shop_pg_num ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

#shop_pg_num ul li {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

FIXED (our stupidity)
We fixed the issue. There was some old code that made the page responsive that was somehow messing up the styling for the images. We got rid of that old code and now it is working beautifully now. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Please post some code including your CSS, so we can have a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Post your code or link

Comment: Post code or link, there so much way for images loading problems

Comment: Possible issue would be that you are giving images absolute path instead of giving them relative path thats y they are loading on your local system but not loading on server

Comment: If your images are very tiny then you can convert them to base64 and include them as a part of your html.

Comment: @RajatBhadauria I just tried changed the path and the issue is still the there, unfortunately.

Comment: instead of giving  $("<img/>")[0].src = this;  try giving  $("<img/>")[0].src = JSON.stringify(this);

Comment: inside the function preload

Comment: @RajatBhadauria I changed it to "../img/shopView"

Comment: ../img will point to root directory .......can you check your console when you are running your code on server is it showing any Error over there ??

Comment: @RajaBhadauria I just changed the preload function. The issue occurs less frequently, but it still shows up. Thanks for helping though. I'd love you if you have any more suggestions. This one has me stumped.

Comment: @RajatBhadauria Lol we just checked that and we had several errors. The images are not found. Standard 404 error. How though? If the images are loading on the page?

Comment: so the real issue now is of path ....images are not being found on server

Comment: try getting the images from the url in the web server .....like                  server-url/images/anyimage.jpg

Comment: I meant like this  http://your_server_name/img/shopView/IMG_1932.jpg

Comment: The problem is in  giving the path to images ...Server where you hosted your website is not able to find the images

Comment: nvm the errors are coming from the preload function. There are no errors when loading a specific image.

Comment: @RajatBhadauria If it were the image paths, then how come the images sometimes load when the page is refreshed?

Comment: $("<img/>")[0].src = this;    instead of giving this  give this  $("img")[0].src = this;        inside the preload function

Comment: $("img")[0].src = this;  gives an error of src undefined.

Comment: Here is the link to our shop page

Comment: http://thelittlepenguinshop.com/shop.php

Comment: this is the original code without unchanged code @rajatbhafdauria

Comment: fixed the issue. There was some old code that made the page responsive that was somehow messing up the styling for the images. We got rid of that it is working beautifully now.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css file

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 // css for image here. 
}
```

if you want to know more specific. Share your code!.